# Python: ftfy causes app crash when compiled to exe using pyinstaller, cx_freeze or p2exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, py2exe, cx-freeze

Whenever I import `ftfy`, and use it in my python script apps, I have no problems at all.

If I compile to binary exe using `pyinstaller`, `cx_freeze` or `py2exe`, my app will compile without problems, but crashes every time time when I run the app.

The reason it crashes is because it cannot find the `char_classes.dat` file from `chardata.py`.

Here is a typical output that I get when I run my app after compiling with pyinstaller and it crashes:

> File "C:\WinPy34\python-3.4.3.amd64\Lib\site-
>   packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 363, in
>   load_module exec(bytecode, module.**dict**)
>
> File
>   "C:\WinPy34\python-3.4.3.amd64\Lib\site-packages\ftfy\chardata.py",
>   line 141, in CHAR_CLASS_STRING =
>   zlib.decompress(resource_string(**name**,
>   'char_classes.dat')).decode('ascii')
>
> File
>   "C:\WinPy34\python-3.4.3.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.p
>   y", line 1173, in resource_string self, resource_name
>
> File
>   "C:\WinPy34\python-3.4.3.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.p
>   y", line 1605, in get_resource_string
>
> return self._get(self._fn(self.module_path, resource_name))
>
> File
>   "C:\WinPy34\python-3.4.3.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pkg_resources__init__.p
>   y", line 1683, in _get
>        return self.loader.get_data(path)    File "C:\WinPy34\python-3.4.3.amd64\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimo
>   d03_importers.py", line 445, in get_data with open(path, 'rb') as fp:
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'C:\Users\BILLTH~1\Ap
>   pData\Local\Temp\_MEI64282\ftfy\char_classes.dat'
>
> d2e returned -1

This output says that it cannot find the `char_classes.dat` file even though that file is there -- as plain as day -- within the ftfy module in the site-packages  directory.

Comment: I know this is old, but was wondering if you ever found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

According to your log, the file looked for is `C:\Users\BILLTH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI64282\ftfy\char_classes.dat`.

As it is a temporary directory, I guess that it is where the archive was extracted. These compiler tools create an auto-extractable zip archive which extracts the sources and the embeded python interpreter in a temporary folder, sets up some environment variables, and runs python with the right parameters.

Therefore, I guess that your `char_classes.dat` file was not embeded by the tool, probably because the tool doesn't see the dependency.

Using pyinstaller, you will probably find the section of the documentation [Using Data Files from a Module](http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#using-data-files-from-a-module) interesting, and add the following argument to your `Analysis` call:

```
datas=[('ftfy\char_classes.dat', 'ftfy')]
```

Comment: @madprog...Thanks for your input. I've already tried altering both the datas and binaries in the Pyinstaller spec file. It didn't work. The char_classes.dat file is a binary file.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a limited solution to this issue.

For me, I was unable to get [Using Data Files from a Module](http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#using-data-files-from-a-module) to work. I also had no luck with any kind of data specification from a hook file.

However, it worked using a relative path from my .spec file (which is automatically created in the working directory where you run PyInstaller).

In my case,

```
a = Analysis(['ShellClient.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\workspaces\\ScoutSheet\\ScoutSheet\\ScoutSheet.Parsers.NERParsers'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[
                ("./env/Lib/site-packages/ftfy/char_classes.dat", "ftfy")
             ],
             hiddenimports=["ftfy"],
             hookspath=['.\\PyinstallerHooks'],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
```

The important line being

```
datas=[
    ("./env/Lib/site-packages/ftfy/char_classes.dat", "ftfy")
],
```